# How to auto-refresh my browser on save while using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, eclipse-plugin

I(a beginner to development) use **Eclipse IDE** for developing web-applications and **Apache Tomcat server**. It becomes very tidious to refresh the browser everytime I want to see the changes I have made from my last refresh. Is there any plugin or code which can do this **Auto-refresh work** for me in Google Chrome?
I searched it on Google but was not able to find any good solutions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find the solution??

Answer (score 0):

I just installed browser extension on my FireFox.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-refresh-page/
Then I set the refresh rate of 1 second.
It is a little annoying seeing the page title blinks every one second.